# working with two repositories in one root folder in git?

Tags: git

let's say I have a project with with a set of files that are going to be used as foundation for ALL my other projects, this project has its own local and remote repository

what I want to do is to clone this base repo and start doing my stuff for my new project so I create a new local and remote repo. but tomorrow I found a bug in a file that belongs to the "base" project I would like to change it in here and push to "base" repo only files related to that project, how can I achieve this?

Comment: This really depends on how your project is constructed but you could use branches. Maintain a ``base`` branch and do all of your core work there -- add new features and bugfixes. Then when starting a new project, simply branch off and continuously merge ``base`` into ``new_project``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you don't need to work with the two repositories in the same directory, as the question title suggests.

It seems you already have two projects, `base` and `derived`, both with remotes (I'll call them `rbase` and `rderived`). I see two good approaches for what you want:

### Multiple remotes

Git can work with multiple remotes configured for each clone. This is a good solution if the `derived` directory structure is exactly the same as `base` structure.

So, your `base` clone has one remote configured (`origin`), pointing to the `rbase` server. And it has some commits with common files.

You `derived` clone has initially one remote configured (`origin`), poiting to the `rderived` server. The `rderived` server was created forking `rbase`, so your `derived` starts with the same commits in `base`.

Now, you add the `rbase` as a remote for `derived`:

```
git remote add base path/to/rbase
git fetch base
```

From the `derived` clone, you can access `master` branch from `base` as `base/master`, can start some work in this branch, commit and push it to `rbase`:

```
git push base local-branch-with-base-changes:master
```

Note that you must take care of working in `base` in a separated branch (based on `base/master` or whatever other branch name from `base`), otherwise, you can't push it to `base`, as it would push `derived` commits (and probably be non-fast-forward). To keep both `master` and `base/master` in sync, some merge commits are required.

See `git remote --help` for more information.

### Submodules

The Git also support a repository inside another. This solution will work if the `derived` directory structure contains some directory with the `base` directory structure. In other works, `base` is a subdirectory of `derived` and, as both as repositories, `base` is a *git submodule* of `derived`

When working with submodules, the submodule directory is actually a simple clone of the submodule's repository. All changes made inside that directory are actually changes in the submodule repository, not on the superproject repository.

In `derived`:

```
git submodule add path/to/rbase path/inside/derived/to/clone/base
git submodule update
```

Then, after editing files inside `path/inside/derived/to/clone/base`, enter that directory, create a commit and push it. Its `origin` will point to `rbase`.

Using submodules, there is no need of merge commits. The sync between `derived`'s clone of `rbase` and `base` are simply commits in `derived` indicating the new `HEAD` for the submodule.

See `git submodule --help` for more information.